# Android list selector semitransparent

Tags: java, android, listview

If this has already been asked, forgive me. But I'm wondering if there is a simple way to adjust the transparency for `ListView` selection. I know how to change the color, but is there any attribute that allows to adjust the transparency? Or would you have to upload some custom background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by transparent you mean see-through, and by ListView selection you mean a single item of the ListView, then its called [alpha](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3aalpha). The link should show you the info for the XML, but you can also set it using `setAlpha()`, which is accessible to any View.